# How do I share the contents of a file two-way between host and container?

Tags: nginx, docker

I am pretty sure it used to work this way, but now I can't make it work anymore... This is the problem:

```
 $ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name frontend -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v $(pwd)/htpasswd:/htpasswd nginx
```

I want to have this `nginx.conf` file that I want to edit in the host and, then, simply run

```
$ docker exec -ti frontend nginx -s reload
```

And have my frontend server reloaded. But I can't see the changes in `nginx.conf` from inside the container. Why is that?

In case this helps:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "39ceafd41f7576638d4b129ea90b0522aa61f25d62e68e361de905638ba74f60",
        "Created": "2016-07-07T18:59:35.917569545Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 17786,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-07-07T18:59:36.241298894Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:0d409d33b27e47423b049f7f863faa08655a8c901749c2b25b93ca67d01a470d",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/39ceafd41f7576638d4b129ea90b0522aa61f25d62e68e361de905638ba74f60/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/39ceafd41f7576638d4b129ea90b0522aa61f25d62e68e361de905638ba74f60/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/39ceafd41f7576638d4b129ea90b0522aa61f25d62e68e361de905638ba74f60/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/39ceafd41f7576638d4b129ea90b0522aa61f25d62e68e361de905638ba74f60/39ceafd41f7576638d4b129ea90b0522aa61f25d62e68e361de905638ba74f60-json.log",
        "Name": "/frontend",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "devicemapper",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/jpmelos/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
                "/home/jpmelos/htpasswd:/htpasswd"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "infra",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "StorageOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "BlkioIOps": 0,
            "BlkioBps": 0,
            "SandboxSize": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "devicemapper",
            "Data": {
                "DeviceId": "3660",
                "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-3147678-71e674d2c1754f73d3fdd933a1971bf8464f6aa6b738dc818a668beb96a4e6ea",
                "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/home/jpmelos/nginx.conf",
                "Destination": "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Source": "/home/jpmelos/htpasswd",
                "Destination": "/htpasswd",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "39ceafd41f75",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "443/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.11.1-1~jessie"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "Image": "nginx",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "c20b1912f3689cf6b82d19b2ae3173e050b3958e266dd19dd047aeccacabef55",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": null,
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c20b1912f368",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "infra": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "4598916660ed5453a5ec48412452b00ef6dce24f64b5e315b625596a806442c1",
                    "EndpointID": "9e7d50cdfbdcec31331655b167ec0e6c5ee20b6e3cc7122222706f99418732d2",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Interesting bit: the `Mounts` section says the mountpoints are `rprivate`. This might be the problem, but I researched and I couldn't find anything about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is that Docker does not allow editing shared files, just files inside shared directories. When I put my configuration files inside a shared directory and included them from `nginx.conf`, then it all worked.